# Warning CS0618 'Resource.Style.ThemeHoloDialog' is obsolete: 'deprecated'

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin.Android project. And have this code:-

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(_activity, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloDialog));
```

This line is showing a warning as follows in screenshot:

[image: Warning CS0618 'Resource.Style.ThemeHoloDialog' is obsolete: 'deprecated']

I want to avoid the use of deprecated methods.

How could I fix this problem?

What is the non-deprecated form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After litle googling found answer from this official android page https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog

[image]

We can use  `Android.Resource.Style.ThemeMaterialLightDialogAlert`